# Which type of join do I need?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables, contracts and salesmen.
Recently I've discovered some errors in the data, some contracts have salesid's not found in 'salesmen', I suspect an accidental deletion or an input error of some kind.

Which join should I use to find all contracts that dont 'belong' to a salesman, in other words, the contract.salesid not found in the salesmen.id column.

It should be a right outer join but the results arent coming up right.

Comment: Please post the table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.contract_id FROM contract c
LEFT OUTER JOIN salesmen s ON s.salesman_id = c.salesman_id
WHERE c.salesman_id IS NULL
```

would be my guess.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for an "anti-join".  [Explain Extended](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) talks about the three ways to do this in MySQL:

- A left join with a `WHERE __ IS NULL`
- A `NOT IN` clause with a subselect.
- A `NOT EXISTS` clause with a subselect.

Comment: +1: For the ExplainExtended link, but don't forget [this one, about when columns are nullable](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Comment: +1 for antijoin (a.k.a. semi difference) @OMGPonies: it seems the article about null semantics relating to the feature is longer than the article about the feature itself! A good advert for the "avoid nulls" campaign :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for `contract.salesid` not found in the `salesmen.id`, you can use `NOT IN()` rather than a join.

```
SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE salesid NOT IN (SELECT id FROM salesmen);
```

The above will return everything from `contracts` having `salesid` that matches no existing `salesmen.id`.  Using `NOT IN ()` on large tables can be slower than doing it with a `JOIN`, but if your tables aren't too large it is usually a more straightforward method to use (in my opinion).

Comment: Michael, your suggestion works perfectly. However I'll accept the answer from 0xCAFEBABE as the right one as I was mainly interested for a JOIN syntax. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @bikey77: See ladenedge's answer for why JOIN syntax is not always the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

`left outer join` if you are joining from contracts to salesman

edit: had order around the wrong way

Comment: so 'select * from contracts c left outer join salesmen s on c.salesid = s.id' will work? I tried it but I'm getting the entire table in the results.

Comment: ah sorry, i misread the question. i had assumed that you wanted to get the salesmen for a contract if they exist. if you want to find missing salesmen, using not exists in a where clause will be easiest

Answer (score 0):

An outer join could indeed do it, but why not simply:

```
select *
from contract c
where c.salesid not in (select s.id
                        from salesmen s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the answer :

```
select * from Contract c 
right outer join Salesmen s on (c.salesid = s.id)
```

Comment: That will give you a list of all contracts; salesmen columns will be NULL if there's no match on the criteria.

Comment: Did you read the question? "Which join should I use to find all contracts that dont 'belong' to a salesman"

Comment: You don't understand -- **ALL** records, the user has to pay attention for NULLs to know what doesn't belong.  Most just want the records that don't belong ;)